# Glassfish & JMS: Why do published messages not arrive at subscribers?

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, mq

I have a Glassfish 3.1.2 server running on a remote machine (JDK 1.6.0_30). The following code is the stand-alone client running in a Java SE environment, connecting to the JMS using a JNDI lookup. The client is publisher and subscriber at the same time.

I created the JMS connection pool and topic as follows:

```
./asadmin create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.ConnectionFactory jms/TopicConnectionFactory
./asadmin create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.Topic jms/TopicUpdate
```

I start two instances of this client. The messages seem to be delivered - no errors - but the messages do not arrive at the subscribers ...

What I am doing wrong ?

Any help appreciated - many thanks in advance!

```
public class JMS implements MessageListener {

    private TopicConnectionFactory factory;
    private TopicConnection connection;
    private Topic topic;

    private void subscribe() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.1.6");
            System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            factory = (TopicConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("jms/TopicConnectionFactory");
            topic = (Topic)ctx.lookup("jms/TopicUpdate");
            connection = factory.createTopicConnection();
            TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.createSubscriber(topic);
            subscriber.setMessageListener(this);
            connection.start();
            while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                sendMessage();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        try {
            TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            TopicPublisher publisher = session.createPublisher(topic);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            message.setText("Message from client.");
            publisher.send(message);
            session.close();
            System.out.println("Message sent.");
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JMS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        System.out.println("Message received.");
    }

    public JMS() {
        subscribe();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JMS();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use true as the first argument when creating a session, the acknowledge mode is ignored and you're assumed to be transacted.  try it with the first argument as false.

Just so it's clear, modify this line of code:

```
TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

to be :

```
TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

In your send message method.

Comment: hey john, many thanks for this hint! it works very fine now :-) !

Answer (score 0):

It's good idea to have publisher and subscriber different.I

Here is code how to subscribe using Spring JMS template.

```
public class MsgReader implements
        SessionAwareMessageListener<Message> {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());

            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

- Spring Bean file.
- Finally load beans.

  public class SpringJMSTest {

  ```
  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"/resource/consumerBean.xml"});
          }
  }
  ```
- Now you will start receiving messages in console.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have split my client class to a publisher and subscriber class and additionally extracted the MessageListener to its own class. But this makes no difference. Any further ideas ?

Comment: It seems to me that, there is some problem with the configuration or host port you are using (by default GF JMS port is 7676) . Why don't you create your JMS destinations and connection factories through the glass fish admin console.. for admin console you need to :- http://gfserver-ip:4848

Comment: this should not make any difference. I tried to create the connection factory and the resource on the web-gui, but then it duplicates the resources to the connection-factory folder. when trying to select this, it raises an "error" on the web-gui. seems to be a bug... thanks anyway.